# In Swift, why does the error "type alias references itself" depend on where the type alias is defined?

Tags: swift, generics, swift-protocols, swift-extensions

I'm using Swift 4.1 in Xcode 9.4.1. I need to create a dictionary that can hold a finite variety of data types as values, so I wanted to define the dictionary as something more specific than `[String: Any]`. I decided to create a protocol, and take advantage of Swift 4's conditional conformance to allow nested dictionaries of the same type. My code looked like this:

```
protocol MetricsValue {}
typealias MetricsDictionary = [String: MetricsValue]

//Now define which types can go in the dictionary:
extension String: MetricsValue {}
extension Dictionary: MetricsValue where Key == String, Value == MetricsDictionary {}
```

This fails to compile, with the error: "Type alias MetricsDictionary references itself." I then tried this, not really expecting it to work:

```
protocol MetricsValue {}

//Now define which types can go in the dictionary:
extension String: FDGoogleMetricsValue {}
extension Dictionary: MetricsValue where Key == String, Value == MetricsDictionary {}

typealias MetricsDictionary = [String: MetricsValue]
```

And it compiles! Defining the type alias below the extension works. Why does the second example compile, but the first example fail?

Edit: After thinking about it, I actually wanted to make `MetricsDictionary` conform to `MetricsValue`, i.e. `extension Dictionary: MetricsValue where Key == String, Value == MetricsValue`, which works without any problems. I was going to delete the question, but it still seems odd, so I'll keep in case other people find it helpful.

Comment: Probably a bug...

Answer (score 1):

It's quite interesting, the code you have provided:

```
protocol MetricsValue {}
typealias MetricsDictionary = [String: MetricsValue]

extension String: MetricsValue {}
extension Dictionary: MetricsValue where Key == String, Value == MetricsDictionary {}
```

fails to compile in Xcode 9.4.1, but it has no problems in Xcode 10.0 beta (10L176w). Also i have compiled the code in online [swift compile](http://online.swiftplayground.run/) with Swift 4.1.2 and it also has no problems.

There was same kind of [bug report](https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-3478) for Xcode 8.2.1 and they fixed it in 8.3. Maybe it presented itself in the current Xcode version.